# Add a photo and tags in a single ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm writing a page where a user can upload a photo, add a comment and tags. Before the photo is uploaded it is displayed to the user. 
Once the user hits post button the data is sent to the database. My problem is that I can't upload both photo and tags at the same time. I'm using TokenInput plugin to catch the tags.

```
<form method="post" action="" class="snap-pic">
  <section class="new-snap-upload">
     <img src="images/newsnap-icon.png" alt="Image" class="newsnapbox">
     <div class="errortext" style="color: red;"></div>
     <input type="file" name="newsnap" id="uploadnewsnap">
     <button id="imgbutton">Upload Snap</button>
  </section>              
  <section class="snapitems">
     <h5>About this outfit</h5>
     <textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="aboutoutfit" class="aboutfit"></textarea>
     <div class="error-items" style="color: red;"></div>
  </section>
  <section class="snaptags">
      <h5>Tags</h5>
      <input type="text" name="tags" class="tagbox-snap">
      <div class="error-tags" style="color: red;"></div>
      <img src='' alt="" class="loader-gif"></img>
  </section>
       <input type="submit" class="submit-snap" name="submit-snap" value="Post!">
</form>
```

When the user click on Upload Snap they get to select the photo they want to upload and it's displayed in the `<img>` tag.
Then when Post is clicked I want to send the data to the database. I'm using this function:

```
$(".snap-pic").on('submit', (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();               
    $(".errortext").text('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "snap-ajax.php",        
        type: "POST",             
        data: new FormData(this), 
        contentType: false,       
        cache: false,             
        processData: false,        
        success: function (data)   
        {
           $(".errortext").text('OK');
        }
    });
    }
 ));
```

To insert tags I'm using this:

```
var names = [];
            $('.tagbox-snap').siblings("ul").find('li p').each(function () {
                names.push($(this).html());
                //names.push($(this).text());//possibly better
                tags = names.join()
            });
 $.ajax ({
            url: "ajax-training.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'tags': tags},
            success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
                    },

            error: function () {
            alert("Problem");
            }
            });
```

However I can't seem to use both functions at the same time. When I use the one for uploading photos I can't use the one for tags and the other way around.
Is there anyway I can send new FormData together with {'tags': tags}? I'm not really sure how to use FormData though.
I'd send it to the same page then.

I'm sorry for a chaotic post and hope this is legible enough. 
Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN FormData docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) you can use `FormData.append()`.

Code would be something like:

```
$(".snap-pic").on('submit', (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();               
    $(".errortext").text('Loading...');
    var postData = new FormData(this);
     var tags = // get your tags data here

    // add tags to FormData
    postData.append('tags', tags);


    $.ajax({
        url: "snap-ajax.php",        
        type: "POST",             
        data: postData, 
        contentType: false,       
        cache: false,             
        processData: false,        
        success: function (data)   
        {
           $(".errortext").text('OK');
        }
    });
    }
 ));
```